# JAX-WS @webMethod manual deserialization

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I have a SOAP-based endpoint which receives a XML message, validates it and replies with other xml. For xml processing I use JAXB.
My endpoint looks like:

```
@WebMethod
public SomeOutput processXML(SomeInput input){
    ...
}
```

Deserealization happens correctly if XML is valid. But I get an exeption if the client sends another structure. How to receive raw XML and validate it through xsd schema before automatic deserialization?

Comment: I found a better way using String as a parameter and receive data as a xml string and unmarshal with JAXB to Java object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JAX-WS you can use handlers to handle faults. When an error occurs during the unmarshalling handlers that the user added can take care of the errors if needed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/Handler.html

If you want to get the raw xml message as input of your webservice instead of letting JAX-WS take care of that for you (which gives you more control but also more work) you can do what they describe at this website: http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-jax-ws-web

Comment: yes, but If there is no error umarshaling happens twice. Which is not a good practice.

Comment: I don't get it. Why would a message get unmarshalled twice?

Comment: in the handler, when I manually try to unmarshal input and if the input is valid, automatic deserialization(unmarshaling) happens in @WebMethod public SomeOutput processXML(SomeInput input){..}. Am I right?

Comment: But when you are in the handlers method handleFault you already know that the structure was wrong, no reason to try to validate again. I remember vaguely that there is a way to tell JAX-WS to just send the xml message to the webservice instead of the object, that is maybe what you need, and then you can do your own stuff. Will see if I can find info about that.

Comment: I think its this to receive the raw xml in the web service: http://java.dzone.com/articles/implementing-jax-ws-web

Comment: I agree with you, but if the structure was valid, unmarshaling happens twice